# $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X,Y^{2}-1)$ is this a maximal ideal or a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X,Y^{2}-1)$ is this a maximal ideal or a prime ideal?

So far i got:

$\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X,Y^{2}-1) = \left(\mathbb{Q}[Y]\right)X/(X,Y^{2}-1)$ is isomorphic to 
$\mathbb{Q}[Y]/(Y^{2}-1)$ = $\mathbb{Q}[Y]/(Y+1)(Y-1)$. Because we now have zero divisors this can't be a domain, so its cant be a prime/maximal ideal.

I don't trust my proof because i don't know why the second step would be valid.

Please help :)

Kees

Comment: Great job explaining your question and writing down your work :) Keep up the good work!

Comment: Added a solution reassuring you about the steps you took.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. The polynomials $Y - 1$ and $Y + 1$ are both outside the ideal $(X, Y^2 - 1)$, but their product is contained in it, thus it cannot be a prime ideal. Since any maximal ideal is prime, it cannot be maximal either.

Comment: is the second-->third step of my proof valid?

Comment: @KeesTil I see no mistakes in your proof, I've just reworded it in my answer so it doesn't mention quotient rings. Not that they do any harm. I could've said $Y-1$ and $Y+1$ are both non-zero in $\Bbb Q[Y]/(Y^2 - 1)$, but their product is zero. Thus $\Bbb Q[Y]/(Y^2 - 1)$ is not a domain and therefore $Y^2 - 1$ is not prime in $\Bbb Q[Y]$. The "removal" of the abundant $X$ was also correct, although, once again, the argument works just fine with it still there (if you keep it it will a bit harder to see your way to a solution unless you're used to working with these things, though).

Answer (score 5):

Let's reassure you that the step of your reasoning you were unsure about can be done rigorously.

It's definitely right that $\Bbb Q[X,Y]=(\Bbb Q[X])[Y]$.

Then looking at $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]/(X,Y^{2}-1) = \left(\mathbb{Q}[Y]\right)[X]/(X,Y^{2}-1)$, the idea would be to apply an isomorphism theorem to say that:

$$
\left(\mathbb{Q}[Y]\right)[X]/(X,Y^{2}-1)\cong \frac{\mathbb{Q}[Y][X]/(X)}{(X,Y^{2}-1) /(X)}
$$

The top is obviously $\Bbb Q[y]$ under the evaluation map $X\to 0$, and the bottom is the ideal $(Y^2-1)$ in that ring, so you indeed have $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[Y]}{(Y^{2}-1) }$.

Comment: thanks! I knew i had to use the third isomorphism, but i didn't see which 'I' to construct.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be maximal, as it is properly contained in both of the (distinct) maximal ideals $(X,Y\pm 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the end you don't need the equality $Q[Y]/(Y^2−1) = Q[Y]/(Y+1)(Y−1) $. It is sufficient to say that $(Y-1)$ and $(y+1)$ are zero divisors, so this can't be a domain, and therefore can't be prime (or maximal).